# Adding ProgressBar to DataGrid column

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application where i would like to show a progressbar in a datagrid column. Here's what i have so far:

```
    <DataGrid Name="dgOrders" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#35000000" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#35000000" BorderThickness="1" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="False" IsReadOnly="True" RowHeaderWidth="0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Progress" Width="*" Visibility="Hidden">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Path=ProgressValue, Mode=OneWay}" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

This works and i get nice progressbars on every row. Now here comes the part i get confused: i use this datagrid inside a `UserControl` what is then used in a `Page` like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Controls:OrderDataGrid x:Name="cntrlOrderDataGrid"></Controls:OrderDataGrid>
</Grid>
```

And the pages are loaded from a `Frame`.

The question is how and where i should implement the class and the `ProgressValue` so it would update my `ProgressBar` value binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ProgressValue should exists in the ItemsSource that you assign to grid, it is not related if you are using usercontrols and frames or not

Something like this

```
public class SomeVal : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public int ProgressValue{...}
}

datagrid.ItemsSource = new [] {new SomeVal()};
```